# React production rendering blank with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, webpack, laravel-blade

I didn't want to post this question but it seems like I have tried everything possible.

My index_bundle.js is created for production through webpack.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env':{
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }
}),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress:{
    // warnings: true
  }
})
```

I have Laravel routes set to use wildcards to make way for the react router aswell.

React is rendering the actual website in development mode but the production mode won't render anything but "react-empty".

[image: react-emptys]

There are no errors in the console, other than development build error, prior to making webpack production-ready.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer, I will post it in case someone else needs help in the future.

Using React (w/ React-router) requires the domain to be a virtual host and not just localhost/{slug}. It turns out react-router was trying to display the page "pie-test/public".